# Bright solid avatars are really distracting

Tags: feature-request, avatar

We've gone from geometric shape designs to (sometimes brightly) colored solid blocks, which are a strong visual draw, especially in warning orange/red.

[image: bright orange and pink avatars in a stack overflow question list]

I don't really mind the solid blocks, but please limit it to more subdued colors.

Comment: These avatars are provided by Google for users who log in with Google and don't have a Google profile picture. (Gravatar is still used by default for users who have an email but no Google or Facebook avatar.) They are indeed ugly.

Comment: The [registration page for Google users](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zIRLI.png) prompts them to upload a different avatar if they want, but doesn't provide Gravatar as an option.

Comment: @Jeremy Bummer, as it sounds like it would be very difficult to separate them from legitimate profile pictures. They are not well suited for SOs subdued palette.

Comment: I prefer the solid blocks to the gravatars. They're all messy and quasi-psychedelic. :D

Answer (score 14):

I say **no**: these avatars are not obscene or offensive, so there is no need to limit their use.

These avatars are just the default for people who sign in with Google who don't have an image associated with their Google account either. If you want, you can block images from "googleusercontent.com". (Doing this will also block images of people who have set their Google profile image to something else.)

Comment: I honestly find Gravatar avatars worse. Sorry. With that said, I don't think they are really *bad*, more like it's hard to remember or distinguish them. They may as well all be the same or just not there, as far as I'm concerned. I don't think it's anything that really needs action, though - if people don't want avatars or want Gravatar ones, that's fine. It's just me who might have trouble remembering them.